# have to randomly generated number to match in python?

Tags: python, loops, random

Hi all wish y'all stay safe!

I'm trying to figure out how to write a simple code to count how many tries it takes to have 2 random numbers to match using pythong randint(), while keeping count how many times it takes.

my thought is :

```
ran1 = random.randint(1,10)

ran2 = random.randint(1,10)

count = 0
while ran1 != ran2:
  count = count+1
  print(count)
  if ran1 == ran2:
    break
    print(count)
```

does this make sense? something is wrong but i dont know what... it just keeps going and no stop lol

thank you!

Comment: You'll have to pick some new random numbers at some point… currently you're only picking two numbers once, and then repeatedly compare them.

Comment: And it is useless to have an instruction if a loop after a break... move the print out of the loop!

Comment: If the program didn't stop, it means that the program didn't generate two similar numbers at once. Also, your print statement should be before the break or else you won't see the message.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta lol thanks! i just realized i embarassed myself out publicly

Comment: @Mervin Hemaraju thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to chose random value again once you chose them when they are not matched. to do that you can use while loop and inside it you can take random no each time when there is no match and if there is match then you can break the loop and print out the result

```
import random
count = 0
while True:
    count +=1
    ran1 = random.randint(1,10)
    ran2 = random.randint(1,10)
    if ran1==ran2:
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: @lycheelichi clicking the tick to accept the answer is a nice way to say thanks here :)

Comment: @SamMason lol I just noticed there's a tick!and what it is for!  thank you!